# Recreate vector from print() console output

Tags: r

Regrettably often you see questions on SO that present data in a format
that's not reproducible; often just the copied result of `print()` ...

```
set.seed(1)

x <- sample(LETTERS, 40, replace = T)
y <- rnorm(20)
```

... such as this:

```
x
 [1] "G" "J" "O" "X" "F" "X" "Y" "R" "Q" "B" "F" "E" "R" "J" "U" "M" "S"
[18] "Z" "J" "U" "Y" "F" "Q" "D" "G" "K" "A" "J" "W" "I" "M" "P" "M" "E"
[35] "V" "R" "U" "C" "S" "K"
```

... or this:

```
y
 [1]  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170  0.61982575
 [6] -0.05612874 -0.15579551 -1.47075238 -0.47815006  0.41794156
[11]  1.35867955 -0.10278773  0.38767161 -0.05380504 -1.37705956
[16] -0.41499456 -0.39428995 -0.05931340  1.10002537  0.76317575
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to copy, for example, the text from the chunk above to my clipboard, and call some function `foo()` such that `all.equal(foo(), x)` for discrete data types, and `all(near(foo(), y))` for floats (given the printed accuracy).

Is there an easy way to (approximately) reconstruct a simple vector from the copied result of `print()`'ing it?

---

**Edit:** Ironically, I realized that my own example wasn't exactly fully reproducible. Here's the code to create the copied print output:

```
y_printed <- capture.output(y)
```

Comment: I can imagine that a simple implementation would not be too difficult, so while such implementations are of course welcome, I'm more wondering whether this functionality is already available in a published package.

Comment: It would be every nice to have such a function and link it to a plugin, hotkey or snipper. Some features would be date detection, try to separate by multiple spaces to handle character values containing spaces, detect if there are column headers or not, remove `#` characters that start a line, support list outputs etc... package `datapasta` had something similar this for tables you'd copy paste from the web but last time I checked it didn't work so well on SO tables.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yeah, that would be useful. Thinking about packages, it does seem like something like this would be a good fit for enhancing **datapasta**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `scan` for that problem.

Can you make a function out of the below code?

```
y <-
  '[1]  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170  0.61982575
 [6] -0.05612874 -0.15579551 -1.47075238 -0.47815006  0.41794156
[11]  1.35867955 -0.10278773  0.38767161 -0.05380504 -1.37705956
[16] -0.41499456 -0.39428995 -0.05931340  1.10002537  0.76317575'

y <- scan(what = character(), text = y)
y <- sub("^\\s*\\[\\d+\\]", "", y)
y <- as.numeric(y[y != ""])
```

With the suggestion in the comment by @Moody_Mudskipper,

> Pattern can be updated to "^\s*\[\d+\]" to support OP's example (which starts by a space).

a function could be

```
recreateVector <- function(X, numeric = TRUE, quiet = FALSE){
  X <- scan(what = character(), text = X, quiet = quiet)
  X <- sub("^\\s*\\[\\d+\\]", "", X)
  X <- X[X != ""]
  if(numeric) X <- as.numeric(X)
  X
}


recreateVector(y)   # Use the original y
#Read 24 items
# [1]  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170  0.61982575
# [6] -0.05612874 -0.15579551 -1.47075238 -0.47815006  0.41794156
#[11]  1.35867955 -0.10278773  0.38767161 -0.05380504 -1.37705956
#[16] -0.41499456 -0.39428995 -0.05931340  1.10002537  0.76317575
```

With a character vector, set argument `numeric = FALSE`, the default is `TRUE`.

```
x <-
'[1] "G" "J" "O" "X" "F" "X" "Y" "R" "Q" "B" "F" "E" "R" "J" "U" "M" "S"
[18] "Z" "J" "U" "Y" "F" "Q" "D" "G" "K" "A" "J" "W" "I" "M" "P" "M" "E"
[35] "V" "R" "U" "C" "S" "K"'

recreateVector(x, numeric = FALSE)
#Read 43 items
# [1] "G" "J" "O" "X" "F" "X" "Y" "R" "Q" "B" "F" "E" "R" "J" "U"
#[16] "M" "S" "Z" "J" "U" "Y" "F" "Q" "D" "G" "K" "A" "J" "W" "I"
#[31] "M" "P" "M" "E" "V" "R" "U" "C" "S" "K"
```

Note the argument `quiet`. I have set the default to `FALSE`, like in the definition of `scan` because I prefer to see whether anything was actually read in.

Comment: I feel like the numeric argument is slightly pointless, since there are more options than simply string or numeric. Nice solution, though!

Comment: I like it: `scan()` is a new friend to me! Some heuristic would definitely be useful for guessing the type, though.

Comment: I believe `data.table::fread` guesses the type, maybe the solution can be adapted to leverage it. Pattern can be updated to `"^\\s*\\[\\d+\\]"` to support OP's example (which starts by a space).

Answer (score 2):

We can mimic the guess on data type done when reading CSV files:

```
library(tidyverse)
unprint <- function(s) {
  s %>% str_replace_all(" *\\[\\d+\\] *","") %>% str_replace_all(" +","\n") %>% 
  textConnection %>% read.table
}
unprint(' [1]  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170  0.61982575
 [6] -0.05612874 -0.15579551 -1.47075238 -0.47815006  0.41794156
[11]  1.35867955 -0.10278773  0.38767161 -0.05380504 -1.37705956
[16] -0.41499456 -0.39428995 -0.05931340  1.10002537  0.76317575') %>% head

#           V1
#1  0.91897737
#2  0.78213630
#3  0.07456498
#4 -1.98935170
#5  0.61982575
#6 -0.05612874


unprint(' [1] "G" "J" "O" "X" "F" "X" "Y" "R" "Q" "B" "F" "E" "R" "J" "U" "M" "S"
[18] "Z" "J" "U" "Y" "F" "Q" "D" "G" "K" "A" "J" "W" "I" "M" "P" "M" "E"
[35] "V" "R" "U" "C" "S" "K"') %>% head

#  V1
#1  G
#2  J
#3  O
#4  X
#5  F
#6  X
```

**A more elaborated version to handle brackets in strings :**
Also gives the correct output : a vector, not a data frame.

```
unprint <- function(s) {
  t <- s %>% textConnection %>% readLines %>% 
    str_replace(" *\\[\\d+\\] *","") %>%
    paste(collapse=' ') %>% str_replace_all(" ","\n") %>% 
    textConnection %>% read.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
  t$V1 %>% str_replace_all("\n"," ")
}

x <- unprint(' [1] "x + y  [1]" "x + z  [2]"')
x
#[1] "x + y  [1]" "x + z  [2]"
```

Comment: I think using `\\s` in regular expressions is a bit more explicit

Comment: Type guessing is definitely useful; the string replaces have me a bit worried though, e.g. (a _slightly_ contrived example) `unprint('[1] "x + y [1]"')`

Answer (score 0):

For my use, I ended up modifying @RuiBarradas' answer a little bit to include
some features I wanted: reading from the clipboard, and type guessing (with
the help of **readr**).

```r
rescue_vector <- function(x = readClipboard()) {
  x <- gsub("(^|\n)\\s*\\[\\d+\\]", "", x)
  x <- scan(text = x, what = character(),
            allowEscapes = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
  readr::parse_guess(x, na = character())
}
```

It works on the given the example data:

```r
set.seed(1)

x <- sample(LETTERS, 40, replace = TRUE)
all.equal(x, rescue_vector(capture.output(x)))
#> [1] TRUE

y <- rnorm(20)
all.equal(y, rescue_vector(capture.output(y)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

And reads from the clipboard:

```r
writeClipboard(capture.output(y))
all.equal(y, rescue_vector())
#> [1] TRUE
```

And also some strange cases:

```r
z <- c("[1] first \n second", "[2] + 1")
all.equal(z, rescue_vector(capture.output(z)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

But missing values remain an issue:

```r
na <- c("", "NA", NA)
rescue_vector(capture.output(na))
#> [1] "" NA NA
```

As @Moody_Mudskipper mentioned in the comments, further developments could
include rescue attempts for pasted tables, too.